# custom template for each category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

We have 4 categories like Furniture / Cloths/ Mobile etc.

What I am looking for is 4 different template style for each category like if furniture we want to use template1, for cloths we will use template 2.

Is there any way to do it in woocommerce? I am working in twenty nineteen theme.

I have gone through `archive.php` and tried to make another PHP file for a different category but it does not work.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: minor grammar improvements

Comment: You don't need to create additional templates, you can [override woocommerce templates via your active theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) and use on the same template some `if` `elseif` statements using [`is_product_category()` conditional tag](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5)… So no need of multiple templates.